# Kentico 7: get only visible menu items in MVC VB?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-4, kentico

I need to get all of the visible nav menu items in a kentico 7 site. So far, I have the following:

`Dim stuff As TreeNodeDataSet = TreeHelper.SelectNodes("/SiteSection/%")`

which returns EVERYTHING (which I don't need). Limiting by class "CMS.MenuItem" narrows it down but not usably... it still returns a bunch of stuff that isn't visible.

Any suggestions?

Comment: when you say "isn't visible" is that content that is "unpublished"

Comment: This is the navigation menu so when the page loads, I need only the top level navigation menu items and any subs that are under them when the mouse hovers over them and should not include any folder items, just nav items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the method overload that lets you pass in True for the SelectOnlyPublished value and for the nesting level pass in 1.

```
Dim stuff As TreeNodeDataSet = TreeHelper.SelectNodes("/SiteSection/%",True, "CMS.MenuItem","","nodeorder",1,True)
```

You can also add to the "where clause" something like "DocumentName not in('home','page1','page2')" if you want to exclude some specific documents.

Comment: Very close but it doesn't account for a dynamic level of submenus. If I increase the submenu level (nesting level), I get items that do not appear in the nav menu ever but are still set as published and sitemap

Comment: you can add to the "where clause" something like "DocumentName not in('home','page1','page2')" if you want to exclude some specific documents. As for submenus you may have to do that in a sub query, nested repeater or hierarchical repeater.

Comment: Ah, now that I know that, it looks like that will work. Thank you.